# ¿Cómo asociar distintas url a un mismo php?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url

Tengo un pequeño proyecto en php con varias páginas que varían en función del contenido de un JSON. Adjunto un ejemplo del JSON que estoy utilizando:

```
{
"posts": [
    {
        "slug": "incubadora",
        "name": "Incubadora",
        "current": 2125,
        "goal": 12500,
        "text_preview": "Phasellus quam turpis, feugiat sit amet in, hendrerit in lectus. Praesent sed semper amet bibendum tristique fringilla.",
        "full_description": "All html content",
        "collaborators": 32,
        "img": {
            "name": "pic02.png",
            "alt": "descripcion seo de la imagen de incubadora",
            "url": "http://localhost/images/pic02.png",
            "url_thumbnail": "http://localhost/images/pic02.png"
        }
    },
    {
     ...
    }
]
}
```

El caso es que cambiando el JSON añadiendo mas posts tienen que aparecer en una lista de productos que aparecen en la home. Hasta aquí todo correcto, los post cargan correctamente, si añado más se refleja a tiempo real y demás, pero el problema viene al pulsar sobre un post, la página me tiene que llevar a una url del tipo: `http://localhost/posts/{slug}`.

He probado a crear una carpeta en el proyecto con el nombre del slug y dentro un index.php y funciona, pero no puedo crear una carpeta por cada post porque no se cuantos va a haber ni que slugs van a tener. La idea es administrar todo lo que cuelge de `/posts/` con el mismo fichero php.

Según he leido creo que podría hacerse con el `htaccess` pero no controlo mucho de esto y no acabo de entenderlo bien, cualquier ayuda es bien recibida. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Por qué no creas una página que te genere el contenido en función de un json que le pases? si es incubadora, pasarle el json que contenga el slug "incubadora" completo, y ya construyes la página con los valores del json, ahora bien, esto es viable sólo si la estructura de los json van a ser siempre las mismas

Comment: Simplemente eso, pasas el json a una especie de controlador, y este recibe el json y te construye la página, ahora, la redirección será siempre a la misma página, no tendrás que crear una carpeta e index por cada elemento del json

Comment: Para ir viendo como manejar el json te recomiendo que hagas siempre `echo var_dump(ELJSON)` para ver que te va devolviendo según hagas

Comment: pero necesito que las url exista, que si el usuario pone http://localhost/posts/incubadora le cargue un php con el contenido del json y si pone por ejemplo http://localhost/posts/mesa cargue el mismo php que antes y genera la pagina igual que antes pero con los datos de mesa del json

Comment: el json ya lo recibo en la home el problema es usar el mismo php para todas las url pero cada url sea propia de ese post

Comment: Entonces ahí si vas a tener que entrar en Apache, ese mundo es un tanto más desconocido para mí :(

Comment: claro para mi igual, tema servidor no manejo mucho

Comment: Lo que sí puedes hacer es crear un script en php que te cree esas carpetas y archivos automáticamente, ahora a "mano alzada" no sería capaz de ayudarte, tendría que estudiar el caso, pero me consta que puedes crear carpetas y archivos de forma automática teniendo datos suficientes. La cosa sería sacar del slug el nombre de la carpeta y que php te genere dicha carpeta, y dentro un index php que puedas crear a partir de una plantilla que hagas, que recoja los datos y cree la página. al entrar al home por ejemplo que se ejecute ese código, revise si hay elementos nuevos en el json y actuar según.

Comment: claro pero eso no me sería viable a largo plazo porque se generarían un montón de ficheros y no tiene mucho tráfico disponible el servidor por lo que no sería eficiente

Comment: Hola David. Si el punto de entrada es `posts/` tú puedes crear en la carpeta `posts` un archivo `index.php` que serviría de controlador. Luego puedes valerte de algo como `PATH_INFO` para saber a qué recurso se quiere acceder, puedes tener un array de recursos válidos y controlar desde el mismo `index.php` las diferentes *partes* (slug) mediante clases de PHP u otros. En el `.htaccess` bastaría con poner algo como esto: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?PATH_INFO=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: @A.Cedano es justo eso, gracias a tu comentario conseguí solucionarlo, tu rewrite funcionaba pero me cogía de fichero el del index.php de la raiz en lugar del de /posts. Muchas gracias

Comment: El `.htaccess` de mi comentario yo lo tengo en lo que sería tu carpeta `posts`, y dentro de la misma carpeta, tengo también un `index.php` que es el controlador. Desde `index.php` yo controlo las diferentes peticiones, o sea, lo que se escriba como *slug*, enviándolas a su destino o mostrando un mensaje de error... porque te pueden escribir algo incorrecto como slug y el programa tiene que controlar eso. Además, también puedes controlar y bloquear si fuera necesario peticiones del tipo `PUT`, `DELETE`, etc. Es como tener tu propia API. Finalmente, desde el mismo `index.php` mando a imprimir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias a [Cedano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/29967/a-cedano) he conseguido  hallar la respuesta. Creando un archivo `.htaccess` en la raíz y modificando el rewrite que puso (me cargaba el index del directorio raíz). Lo que necesitaba era redireccionar todo lo que colgaba de `/posts/` a formato de query string sin que se viera visible en la url.

Con el siguiente rewrite conseguí transformar `http://localhost/posts?slug=incubadora` de manera que la funcionalidad se mantuviese pero visiblemente en la url se viera `http://localhost/posts/incubadora`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?posts/(.*?)/?$ /posts/?slug=$1 [L]
```